# Integrating $ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{e^x+1} \, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

This improper integral has stumped me and not many integration problems give me problems. However, this one made me think over my limit. Finally, as I could not even get started on this problem, I thought to post it here, and have some talented mathematicians look at it. The problem is to integrate:
$$  \int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{e^x+1} \, dx $$

Comment: Nasty answer from WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5E5%2F%28e%5Ex%2B1%29

Comment: Mathematica gives $\frac{31\pi^6}{252}$, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{e^x-1}~dx~=~n!~\zeta(n+1),~$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{e^x+1}~dx~=~n!~\eta(n+1),~$ see the [Riemann $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) functions for more information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$I=\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ \cfrac { { x }^{ 5 } }{ { e }^{ x }+1 } dx= } \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ \cfrac { { e }^{ -x } }{ { 1+e }^{ -x } } { x }^{ 5 }dx }  =\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ \left( \sum _{ r=1 }^{ \infty }{ { \left( -1 \right) }^{ r-1 }{ e }^{ -rx } } { x }^{ 5 } \right) dx } \\ =\sum _{ r=1 }^{ \infty }{ \left\{ \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ { \left( -1 \right) }^{ r-1 }{ e }^{ -rx }{ x }^{ 5 }dx } \right\} }$$

Let $rx=t$:
$$\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ { \left( -1 \right) }^{ r-1 }{ e }^{ -rx }{ x }^{ 5 }dx } ={ \left( -1 \right) }^{ r-1 }\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ { e }^{ -t }{ \left( \cfrac { t }{ r } \right) }^{ 6-1 }\cfrac { dt }{ r } }  =\cfrac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ r-1 } }{ { r }^{ 6 } } \Gamma (6)=120\cfrac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ r-1 } }{ { r }^{ 6 } } \\ \\ \therefore I=\sum _{ r=1 }^{ \infty }{ 120\cfrac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ r-1 } }{ { r }^{ 6 } } } =120\eta \left( 6 \right) =120\left\{ \left( 1-{ 2 }^{ 1-6 } \right) \right\} \zeta \left( 6 \right) \\ \\ =120\times \cfrac { 31 }{ 32 } \zeta \left( 6 \right) =\cfrac { 465 }{ 4 } \zeta \left( 6 \right)$$

$$\zeta \left( 6 \right) =\zeta \left( 2\times 3 \right) =\cfrac { { \left( -1 \right) }^{ 3+1 }{ B }_{ 6 }{ \left( 2\pi \right) }^{ 6 } }{ 2\left( 6 \right) ! } =\cfrac { { \pi }^{ 6 } }{ 945 }$$ 
Note that $B_6$ refers to the $6$th Bernoulli Number $\left(B_6=\frac{1}{42}\right)$:

$$\therefore I=\cfrac { 465 }{ 4 } \times \cfrac { { \pi }^{ 6 } }{ 945 } =\cfrac { { 31\pi }^{ 6 } }{ 252 }$$

Comment: Nice solution. Just one thought: if the integral is in the Lebesgue sense, I think this works, since Dominated Convergence lets you switch integral and series. But if the integral is the improper Riemann integral, then you need uniform convergence, which you have only in $[a,\infty)$, for any $a>0$. Hence, I believe that, formally, one should do the computation for the integral from $a>0$ to $\infty$, and then let $a\to 0$.

Comment: @yagnapatel Thank you for the explanations!

Answer (score 7):

Here is yet another slightly different approach.  Here we enforce the substitution $e^{-x}\to x$ and obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^5}{1+e^{x}}dx&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\left(\log x\right)^5}{1+x}dx\\\\
&=-\frac{d^5}{dy^5}\left.\left(\int_0^1\frac{x^y}{1+x}dx\right)\right|_{y=0}
\end{align}$$

Expanding $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and integrating term by term reveals

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{d^5}{dy^5}\left.\left(\int_0^1\frac{x^y}{1+x}dx\right)\right|_{y=0}&=-\frac{d^5}{dy^5}\left.\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+y}\right)\right|_{y=0}\\\\
&=(5!)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^6}\\\\
&=(5!)\eta(6)\\\\
&=(120)\frac{31\pi^6}{30240}\\\\
&=\frac{31\pi^6}{252}
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the results reported by others as expected!

Answer (score 4):

The key is to express the integrand as the sum of a geometric series, and then switch the order of the integral and the summation.

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^5}{e^x+1}\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^5e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x^5e^{-x}(-e^{-x})^{n-1}\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}x^5e^{-nx}\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^5e^{-nx}\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{u}{n}\right)^5e^{-u}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}\,du$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^6}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^5e^{-u}\,du$ $= \displaystyle\left(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^6}\right)\cdot \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}u^5e^{-u}\,du\right)$ $= \left(1-\dfrac{2}{2^6}\right)\zeta(6) \cdot \Gamma(6)$ $= \dfrac{31}{32} \cdot \dfrac{\pi^6}{945} \cdot 120 = \dfrac{31\pi^6}{252}$.

Here, we have used the following formulas involving the Gamma function, and the Riemann Zeta function: 
$\Gamma(n+1) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}\,dx$ and $(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$.

Comment: Amazingly quick!

Answer (score 3):

**Complex-Analytic Method**

Note that, for a real parameter $k$,
$$\int_0^{\infty}\,\frac{x^5}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x=\left[k^5\right]\left(5!\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\sin(kx)}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x\right)\,,$$
where $\left[k^r\right]\big(f(k)\big)$ denotes the coefficient of the $k^r$-term in the Laurent expansion of $f(k)$ around $k=0$.  Furthermore,
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\sin(kx)}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x=\text{Im}\left(\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\exp(\text{i}kx)}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x\right)\,.$$
For $R>0$ and $\epsilon\in(0,\pi)$, let $Q_{R,\epsilon}$ be the positively oriented rectangle with vertices $0$, $R$, $R+2\pi\text{i}$, and $2\pi\text{i}$, where the line segment $[\pi\text{i}+\epsilon\text{i},\pi\text{i}-\epsilon\text{i}]$ is replaced by a semicircular arc with radius $\epsilon$ centered at $\pi\text{i}$ oriented clockwise going from $\pi\text{i}+\epsilon\text{i}$ to $\pi\text{i}-\epsilon\text{i}$.  If $I(k)$ represents the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\exp(\text{i}kx)}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x$, then
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint\limits_{Q_{R,\epsilon}}\,\frac{\exp(\text{i}kz)}{\exp(z)+1}\,\text{d}z=\big(1-\exp(-2\pi k)\big)\,I(k)-\text{i}\int\limits_{[0,2\pi]\setminus(\pi-\epsilon,\pi+\epsilon)}\,\frac{\exp(-ky)}{\exp(\text{i}y)+1}\,\text{d}y+J_\epsilon\,,$$
where $J_\epsilon$ is the integral of $\frac{\exp(\text{i}kz)}{\exp(z)+1}$ along the clockwise semicircle of radius $\epsilon$ around $z=\pi\text{i}$.  By the Residue Theorem,
$$J_\epsilon=-{\pi\text{i}}\,\text{Res}_{z=\text{i}\pi}\left(\frac{\exp(\text{i}kz)}{\exp(z)+1}\right)+O\left(\epsilon\right)=\pi\text{i}\exp(-\pi k)+O\left(\epsilon\right)\,.$$
Because $Q_{R,\epsilon}$ encloses no poles of $\frac{\exp(\text{i}kz)}{\exp(z)+1}$, we have
$$\oint\limits_{Q_{R,\epsilon}}\,\frac{\exp(\text{i}kz)}{1+\exp(z)}\,\text{d}z=0\,.$$
Also,
$$\frac{\exp(-ky)}{1+\exp(\text{i}y)}=\frac{\exp(-ky)\big(\cos(y/2)-\text{i}\sin(y/2)\big)}{2\cos(y/2)}\,.$$
Hence, by taking $\epsilon\to 0$ and looking only at the imaginary part, we have
$$\begin{align}
2\sinh(\pi k)\exp(-\pi k)\,\text{Im}\big(I(k)\big)
&=-\pi\exp(-\pi k)+\frac12\,\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,\exp(-ky)\,\text{d}y
\\
&=\exp(-\pi k)\left(-\pi+\frac{\sinh(\pi k)}{k}\right)\,.
\end{align}$$
That is,
$$\text{Im}\big(I(k)\big)=\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{csch}(\pi k)\,.$$
From $\text{csch}(x)=\frac{2}{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}$, we can show that
$$\text{csch}(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{6}+\frac{7x^3}{360}-\frac{31x^5}{15120}+O\left(x^7\right)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$\left[k^5\right]\Big(\text{Im}\big(I(k)\big)\Big)=\frac{31\pi^6}{30240}\,.$$
Consequently,
$$\int_0^{\infty}\,\frac{x^5}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x=5!\left(\frac{31\pi^6}{30240}\right)=\frac{31\pi^6}{252}\,.$$

---

In general, $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{2r+1}}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x=\frac{(-1)^{r+1}\,(2r+1)!\,\pi^{2r+2}}{2}\,\Big(\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\big(\text{csch}(x)\big)\Big)\,,$$
for every $r\in\mathbb{N}_0$.  If $\eta$ is the Dirichlet eta function, then
$$\eta(2r+2)=\frac{(-1)^{r+1}\,\pi^{2r+2}}{2}\,\Big(\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\big(\text{csch}(x)\big)\Big)\,,$$
for every $r\in\mathbb{N}_0$.   A similar technique yields
$$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{2r+1}}{\exp(x)-1}\,\text{d}x=\frac{(-1)^r\,(2r+1)!\,\pi^{2r+2}}{2}\,\Big(\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\big(\text{coth}(x)\big)\Big)\,,$$ 
which also means
$$\zeta(2r+2)=\frac{(-1)^r\,\pi^{2r+2}}{2}\,\Big(\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\big(\text{coth}(x)\big)\Big)\,,$$
for every $r\in\mathbb{N}_0$, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.  This shows that
$$\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\big(\text{csch}(x)\big)=-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2r+1}}\right)\,\Big(\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\big(\text{coth}(x)\big)\Big)$$
for all $r=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: Alternatively, $$\eta(2r+2)=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{2r+1}}{\exp(x)+1}\,\text{d}x=\frac{\pi^{2r+2}}{2}\,\Biggl(\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\Big(\text{csc}(x)\Big)\Biggr)$$ and $$\zeta(2r+2)=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{2r+1}}{\exp(x)-1}\,\text{d}x=-\frac{\pi^{2r+2}}{2}\,\Biggl(\left[x^{2r+1}\right]\Big(\text{cot}(x)\Big)\Biggr)$$ for $r=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: In other words, $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\sinh\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\,xu\right)}{\exp(u)+1}\,\text{d}u=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\left(\text{csc}(x)-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\sinh\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\,xu\right)}{\exp(u)-1}\,\text{d}u=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\left(\frac{1}{x}-\text{cot}(x)\right)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\big|\text{Re}(x)\big|<\pi$.

Comment: Furthermore, $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\exp(tu)}{\exp(u)+1}\,\text{d}u=\frac{\pi}{2\,\sin(\pi\,t)}\,\left(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\,\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,\frac{\sin\big(\left(1-2t\right)\,y\big)}{\sin\left(y\right)}\,\text{d}y\right)$$ for all $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\text{Re}(t)<1$.  If $t\in\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$, then $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\exp(tu)}{\exp(u)+1}\,\text{d}u= \frac{2\cdot (-1)^t}{\pi}\,\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,\frac{y\,\cos\big(\left(1-2t\right)\,y\big)}{\sin\left(y\right)}\,\text{d}y\,.$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^5}{e^x+1}\, dx&=\int_0^\infty x^5 \Big(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{2}{e^{2 x}-1}\Big)\, dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^5}{e^x-1} \, dx-2\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^5}{e^{2 x}-1} \, dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^5}{e^x-1} \, dx-2^{-5}\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^5}{e^{ x}-1} \, dx\\
&=(1-2^{-5})\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^5}{e^{ x}-1} \, dx\\
&=(1-2^{-5})\Gamma(6)\zeta(6)\\
\end{align}
note that $\int_0^\infty  \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{ x}-1}\,dx=\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$.
In general then it holds that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^s}{e^x+1} \, dx=(1-2^{-s})\Gamma(s+1)\zeta(s+1)$$